# How do I put extra number at the end of username if duplicate

Tags: php

Hard to explain, and let me show an example.

1. If username **foo** already exists in MySQL I want php script will allow it but to be **foo1**
2. Then if **foo1** exists too, script will generate the username will be **foo2**
3. If **foo2** existed then become **foo3**

How to make like that?

Like [Col. Shrapnel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498886/how-do-i-put-extra-number-at-the-end-of-username-if-duplicate/4499014#4499014) said *Natural increment which seems more sensible. just like "New Folder(3)" stuff in Windows*

Comment: this is possible to do in a script, but is that the best solution? A user might prefer a different username rather than one with a number on the end. I think you'd be better off displaying the user a message saying that username was taken - would they like "name1"...

Comment: The requirement is something like used in stackoverflow

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, lock the table so no other table will write to it at the same time. then do something like this:

```
$name = 'foo';
$first_name = $name;
$i = 0;
do {
  //Check in the database here
  $exists = exists_in_database($name);
  if($exists) {
    $i++;
    $name = $first_name . $i;
  }
}while($exists);
//save $name
```

---

Another method is to select all names in the table starting with "foo" and ending in a number and then finding the largest number. This can be done in SQL.

The first method is better for use cases with only a small risk of collision, since the pattern matching may be slow, but if you have a lot of collisions the latter may be better.

Comment: think better of the algorithm

Comment: Col. Shrapnel, I've updated my answer with another algorithm as well, but for smaller use cases I actually think the first one is better.

Comment: how it is supposed to produce 'foo3'?

Comment: By increasing $i. As you see, I've saved the original name in $first_name before the loop so I can reuse that.

Comment: oh really? care to try it out?

Comment: LOL it's cheating. my name is 'bar2' actually. And your code fails.

Comment: Fails? Where? I've tried it myself :s I've tried these inputs: "foo" => "foo3", "bar" => "bar", "bar2" => "bar2", "foo2" => "foo21". What input did you give it and what was the output?

Comment: I just expect foo3 made for the entered foo2, exactly as it stated by the OP

Comment: Well, if user test already exists then we get test1. But if user test1 alredy exists, the next will be test11 and so on. Its wrong. Also do while loop can be replaced with siple while()

Comment: @ymakux Then you did not use my code :-) Notice that I always build $name based on $first_name that I saved before the loop.

Comment: Ok, just tried this and must admit it works, sorry for being inattentive

Answer (score 3):

First, check if the desired username exists in the database:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS numRows FROM table 
WHERE SUBSTRING(username, 1, CHAR_LENGTH(desiredUserName)) = desiredUserName
```

If numRows is 0, you can leave the username as it is.  If it is 1 you can just add '1' to the end of the username.  It gets a bit more complicated if numRows > 1.  You would need to get the current maxmium number which appends that user name:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(username,(CHAR_LENGTH(desiredUserName) + 1)) AS SIGNED) AS maxNum
FROM table
WHERE SUBSTRING(username,1,CHAR_LENGTH(desiredUserName)) = desiredUserName
ORDER BY CAST(SUBSTRING(username,(CHAR_LENGTH(desiredUserName) + 1)) AS SIGNED) DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Now you just need to add 1 to the returned maxNum and append that to the desired username

Answer (score 0):

Try this one (you need to modifiy this to your needs!)

```
$username_loop = $username = "foo"; // edit: compatibility to usernames n.e. "foo"
$count = 0;
while (){
  $count++;
  $query =  "SELECT username FROM User WHERE username = ".$username_loop;
  $result = mysql_query($query);
  if ($result){
     $username_loop = $username.$count;
  }
  else break;
}
```

Comment: you will get name0, name00, name000 instead of name1, name2, name3, don't you?

Comment: no, that is wrong i will get foo1, foo2, foo3, ... because of  $username = "foo".$count;  You are asuming that i add $count to the username, but i don't

Answer (score 0):

First, use a regular expression to parse out the leading alpha part of the requested username, together with any trailing numeric suffix, something like:

```
^([a-zA-Z_]+)(\d)*$
```

The first group gives you the stem (let's assign this to a variable called UsernameStem) and the second group gives you the number (let's assign this to UsernameNumber). Beware that the user may have not entered a numeric suffix, so you need to check for this special case and assign 0 to UsernameNumber.

You can then issue a SQL statement on your users table as follows:

```
SELECT MAX(username) FROM users WHERE username LIKE :UsernameStem || '%'
```

This will give you the existing username with the highest numeric suffix for the user's desired name.

You can again use the regex above to parse out this maximum number - this time examine the second group returned by your regex match.  You can then add 1 to this number to give the next available username.

Example: the user request "foo21".  The regex will parse out "foo" as the UsernameStem and "21" as the username number.  Assuming that you have a user in your database with the username "foo44", the SQL query will return you this username.  Applying the regex again to this username from your database will enable you to parse out the number "44".  You can then convert this to an int, add 1, then concatenate this with your original UsernameStem.  This will yield "foo45".

Good luck!

Comment: Assuming MySQL is used, you should use [REGEXP](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/pattern-matching.html) to check if the username matches the regular expression instead of using LIKE (because LIKE in your example will also match `foobar` and the like, which will generate erroneous results...).

Comment: I see another problem with my solution, in that when sorting alphabetically (as MAX(username) does), foo11 comes before foo2.  I think the only way to do this is to read ALL the matching users into the application layer, parse out ALL the numeric suffixes as strings, convert them to ints, sort on them, take the maximum and add 1.  This will give the desired numeric ordering, rather than the aphabetic ordering that my original solution achieves.

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like this:

```
// the username
$username = "foo";

// find all users like foo%
$q = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username LIKE '".$username."%' ORDER BY id DESC");

// no users
if (mysql_num_rows($q) == 0) {
    // create $username
}
else {

    $last_num = 0;

    // find all foo users
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($q)) {

        // match foo + number
        if (preg_match("/^".preg_quote($username)."+([0-9]+)$/i", $row['username'], $match)) {

            // extract the number part
            $num = (int) $match[1];

            // set the highest number
            if ($num > $last_num) $last_num = $num;
        }
    }

    // append the highest number to the username
    if ($last_num > 0) $username .= $last_num + 1;

    // create $username
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  $getname   = $_POST['getname'];

  $i++;

  $q =  "SELECT username FROM User WHERE username LIKE '".$getname."%'";

  $r = mysql_query($q);

  if(mysql_num_rows($r) > 0){

    while($row = mysql_fetch_object($r)){
      if($row->username == $getname){
        $uname = $getname.$i;
      }else if($row->username == ($getname.$i)){
        $uname = $getname.$i+1;
      }
      $i++;
    }

  }
  else
  {
   $uname = "foo";
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    while (exists($username)) {
        if (!is_numeric(substr($username, -1, 1))) {
            $username = "{$username}0";
        }
        $username++;
    }

    return $username;
```

You get: test, test1, test2 and so on

Answer (score -2):

Some variation of

```
$number = 1;
$query = "select name from users where username = ".$username.$number;
$res = mysql_query($query);
$num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
while ($num_rows) {
 $number ++;
 $query = "select name from users where username = ".$username.$number;
 $res = mysql_query($query);
 $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($res);
}
```

The above will increment the number until one is found that is not currently in the database.

You will obviously have to edit the values to suit your setup

Comment: think better of the algorithm

Comment: This is fine so long as the database is not large.  Without more information about how OP has setup his server, its difficult to be more precise.

Comment: how it is supposed to produce 'foo3'?

Comment: It will loop through until $num_rows === 0, incrementing $number each time.

Comment: yeah. so, I have entered 'foo2'. will I get foo3 out of your code?

Comment: Ah... I see what you mean.  Fair enough, if foo2 is provided you will get foo21 not foo3.