# Add prefix in my existing username PHP(Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter-3

I am trying to enhance my previous project. In the part of registration module I already done so far the validation of all fields(fields are: name, email, username and password),check if the email and username is already existing.

Right now, I am thinking to add a suggestion for the user if the username is already existing by adding a prefix to the username.

For example in creating a google account, if the username is already taken it will suggest that. See the example below.

[image: Example]

I almost got it but I think my code is wrong or missing something.

```
Scenario 1: If user register existing username
//Assuming all fields are filled
Username: xxxx
```

In my table it will look like this username: xxxx1

It is still correct but when the user tried now to register xxxx1 it will become like this xxxx11 instead of xxxx2

EDITED:

Question: It is now working but it loops so many like abcd until it will give you an error "Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded" and How can I display it to my js?

NOTE: I followed the first answer into this forum ([How do I put extra number at the end of username if duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4498886/how-do-i-put-extra-number-at-the-end-of-username-if-duplicate)) but it gives me so many loops.

**My Controller**

```
$get_username = clean_data($_POST['username']);
$counter = 0;
$where = array(
"username"  => $get_username
);

$check_username = $this->Crud_model->count_result('username','users',$where);
do
{
    if($check_username > 0)
    {
        $counter++;
        $username = $get_username . $counter;
        $insert_user = array(
        'first_name'                => clean_data(ucwords($_POST['first_name'])),
        'last_name'                 => clean_data(ucwords($_POST['last_name'])),
        'profile_picture'           => "profile-picture.jpg",
        'username'                  => $username,
        'email'                     => $_POST['email'],
        'password'                  => hash_password($_POST['password']),
        'status'                    => 1,
        );

        $this->Crud_model->insert('users',$insert_user);
        echo json_encode("success");
    }
}
while ($check_username); 

# code...
$insert_user = array(
'first_name'                => clean_data(ucwords($_POST['first_name'])),
'last_name'                 => clean_data(ucwords($_POST['last_name'])),
'profile_picture'           => "profile-picture.jpg",
'username'                  => $_POST['username'],
'email'                     => $_POST['email'],
'password'                  => hash_password($_POST['password']),
'status'                    => 1,
);

$this->Crud_model->insert('users',$insert_user);


echo json_encode("success");
```

**My model**

```
public function count_result($tag,$table,$where)
{
    $this->db->select($tag);
    $this->db->from($table);
    $this->db->where($where);
    $num_results = $this->db->count_all_results();
    return $num_results;

}
```

**My JS**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#registration-form").on('submit',function(e){
    $.ajax({
      url: base_url+"formsubmit/new_form_submit",
      type: "POST",
      data: $(this).serialize(),
      success:function(data)
      {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);

        if(result === "success")
        {
          $("h5").html("");
          success_message("#success-message-new-account","Create Successful!");
          window.setTimeout(function(){location.href=base_url},2000);
        }
        else{
          $("#first_name_error").html(result.first_name_error);
          $("#last_name_error").html(result.last_name_error);
          $("#username_error").html(result.username_error);
          $("#email_error").html(result.email_error);
          $("#password_error").html(result.password_error);
        }
      },
      error: function(data) {
        alert('error');
      }
    })
    e.preventDefault();
  })
})
```

Comment: Do you want to insert unique username. Suppose username is `xxxxx` and user exists then suggestion will like `xxxxx1' if user `xxxxx1` also exists then suggestion will like `xxxxx11` am I right?

Comment: Yes,I want to have a unique username  and if user xxxxx1 also exists then it will suggest xxxxx2 not xxxxx11

Comment: @Angle, you should pass counter from ajax call

Answer (score 0):

If the username is already existed then extract the last numeric value of username and `add plus 1`.

```
$numVal = strrev( (int)strrev( $get_username ) );// returns last numeric value of username
 if($numVal ){
   $count = count($numVal );//counts number of digit
   $get_username = substr($get_username , 0, -($count));// subtract numeric valur from last of username
  }
 $numVal = $numVal+1;//increment 1 in numeric value
 $username = $get_username.$numVal;//concatenate
```

Tested with following script:

```
$str= "xxxxx"; 
$newstr = strrev( (int)strrev( $str ) );  
if($newstr){
    $count = count($newstr);
  $str = substr($str, 0, -($count));
}
$newstr = $newstr+1;

echo $str.$newstr;
```

if usename is `xxxxx` then becomes `xxxxx1`

if username is `xxxxx1` becomes `xxxxx2`

if username is `xxxxx2` becomes `xxxxx3` and os on.

Comment: I updated my post, can you check why it gives me so many loops

Comment: Try this logic. it's tested at my side

Comment: So Im assuming that $str is equivalent to $_POST['username'] or is it this value?($check_username = $this->Crud_model->count_result('username','users',$where);
)

Comment: Thank you for giving me a logic/idea how to do it, its now working! So now how can I display the suggestion in my view?